# There are 4 girls and 4 boys including John and Martin. In how many ways can they be arranged such that two girls will be behind John and Martin?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> There are 4 girls and 4 boys including John and Martin. In how many
>   ways can they be arranged such that two girls will be behind John and
>   Martin?

There are $2!$ ways to permutate John and Martin. As two girls need to be behind John and Martin, we have that

$$GGBBJMGG$$

Now there are $10$ ways to pick girls and $2!$ ways to permutate boys. Could you assist?

Regards

Comment: Hey, anyone can comment on it?

Comment: How did you get $15$ ways to pick the girls?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig using combinations, ${4}\choose{2}$  ${2}\choose{1}$. Sorry for the typo, It should also be $10$.

Comment: There are only four girls.  If you pick two of them, you should get $\binom{4}{2} = 6$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: The question is somewhat ambiguous.  It could be interpreted to mean that there are exactly two girls behind John and Martin or that there are at least two girls behind John and Martin.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig That's exactly two girls.

Comment: We also don't know, if John and Martin should be seated next to each other, or there could be someone between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There are four boys and four girls, including John and Martin.  In how many ways can they be arranged so that there are exactly two girls behind John and Martin?

Choose six of the eight positions for John, Martin, and the two girls, which can be done in $\binom{8}{6}$ ways.  If there are exactly two girls behind John and Martin, then John and Martin must be in the middle two of the six selected positions.  They can be arranged in those positions in $2!$ ways.  The four girls can be arranged in the remaining four selected positions in $4!$ ways.  The remaining two boys can be arranged in the remaining two positions in $2!$ ways.  Hence, the number of arrangements in which there are exactly two girls behind John and Martin is 
$$\binom{8}{6}2!4!2!$$

> There are four boys and four girls, including John and Martin.  In how many ways can they be arranged so that there are at least two girls behind John and Martin?

Choose six of the eight positions for John, Martin, and the two girls, which can be done in $\binom{8}{6}$ ways.  Since John and Martin must have at least two girls behind them, they must be in the first four of those six selected positions.  Thus, among those six positions, there are $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to select the positions of John and Martin.  John and Martin may be arranged in those two positions in $2!$ ways.  The four girls may be arranged in the remaining four of the original six selected positions in $4!$ ways.  The remaining two boys may be arranged in the remaining two positions in $2!$ ways.  Consequently, there are 
$$\binom{8}{6}\binom{4}{2}2!4!2!$$
arrangements in which there are at least two girls behind John and Martin.

Comment: I didn't get how you evaluated $\binom{8}{6}$

Comment: I assume that you are aware that $\binom{8}{6} = \frac{8!}{6!2!} = 28$, so I am guessing you are wondering why I chose six positions for John, Martin, and the two girls.  By choosing six positions for them and placing John and Martin in the middle two of those six positions, we guarantee that there are exactly two girls behind John and Martin.

Comment: But there's no eight positions remaining for John and Martin.

Comment: I do not understand what you are saying.  Please clarify.

Comment: See you assumed that $\binom{8}{6}$. However, there should be only 6 remaining slots to place John and Martin, which yields $\binom{6}{2}$

Comment: I still do not understand what you are saying.  Please elaborate.

Comment: Consider you have a diagram such as $$BBGGJMGG$$ John and Martin can be rearranged in $\binom{6}{2}$, 6 out of 2. Girls and boys are can also be arranged among themselves, $4!$. John and Martin can be rearranged with $2!$. Hence, we get $\binom{6}{2}4!2!$

Comment: If you are referring to the first question, we choose six of the eight spots for John, Martin, and the four girls.  To ensure that there are exactly two girls behind John and Martin, they must be in the middle two of those six selected positions.  Therefore, there is only one way to choose which two positions John and Martin will occupy (before we arrange them in those positions) once we choose those six positions.

Comment: I'm really unable to get what you mean by eight spots. It should be $6$.

Comment: There are eight positions in line.   Hence, there are eight spots.  You are considering one possible arrangement.  However, notice that the arrangement $$GGJBMGGB$$ is perfectly valid.  There do not need to be two girls in the last two positions.

Comment: Well, I got a different answer: $1440$ from $$\binom{5}{1} \binom{2}{1} \binom{4}{2}4!$$

Comment: You have not explained how you got that answer, so I have no idea what you are counting.

Comment: Suppose such a diagram: $$\_ \space  \_ \space  \_ \space \_ \space \_\space  \_ \space GG$$First we have two possibilities: Either John or Martin seats $\binom{2}{1}$ And then Martin/John can seat in one of remaining 5 spots, $\binom{5}{1}$. Now, we have 2 boys remaining. They can seat in $\binom{4}{2}$ ways. Finally, we can rearrange girls among themselves in $4!$ ways.

Comment: There are a total of eight positions for four boys and four girls.  You have not accounted for that, nor have you accounted for the fact that there are exactly two girls after John and Martin.  You need to decide which six seats will be occupied by John, Martin, and the four girls, then arrange those six people in those seats so that there are exactly two girls behind John and Martin.  Finally, you have to fill the remaining two seats with the other two boys.

Comment: But there won't be any boy/girl behind two girls, that's why.

Comment: Your question does not say that the last two positions will be filled with girls.  $$GGJMGGBB$$ is a perfectly valid configuration.  However, you are correct that there are $$\binom{6}{4}2!4!2! = 1440$$ configurations with two girls in the final two positions.  Choose four of the first six positions for John, Martin, and the first two girls.  John and Martin must be in the last two of these positions.  They can be arranged in those positions in $2!$ ways, the four girls can be arranged in their four positions in $4!$ ways, and the other two boys can be arranged in their positions in $2!$ ways.

Comment: I'm still unable to get this case.